# setting image source to firebase image is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, dom, firebase-realtime-database

I have this html

```
<ul>
 <li><img id="image1" src="images/single_1_thumb.jpg" alt="" data-image="images/single_1.jpg"></li>

</ul>
```

i want to use a firebase storage image as sources for both the src and data-image. I was able to do for src using this code

```
var pic1 = snapshot.child("ProductImageUrl").val();

document.getElementById("image1").src = pic1;
```

but I can't figure how to implement it for data-image. I tried these

```
 document.getElementById("image1").data-image = pic1;
 document.getElementById("image1").'data-image' = pic1;
 document.getElementById("image1").data:image = pic1;
```

the error i get for the first attempt is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

how can I implement setting the firebase image to data-image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to change the attribute value in the DOM

```
document.getElementById('image1').setAttribute('data-image', pic1)
```

or use the [DataSet API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```
document.getElementById('image1').dataset.image = pic1
```